# Restarting a specific pod inside a Deployment

Tags: kubernetes

I want to restart a pod (that is part of a deployment), without having to restart/replace the entire deployment.

I have tried `kubectl replace --force -f file.yaml` but that restarts the whole deployment. I want to just restart the current pod that is live.

Any thoughts are appreciated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Why not just `kubectl delete pod <pod>` ? It will remove your single pod and schedule new in it's place.

If rescheduling is a problem, you could try to kill the process running inside the container in pod with something like `kubectl exec <pod> <container> kill 1`, but some processes might not be willing to surrender easily :)

Comment: Yep that first command was the right one i needed. I added a little more to it so i could restart a specific pod through search - `kubectl delete pods $(kubectl get pods | grep mypod | cut -d ' ' -f1)`. This will help when looking for a specific pod that has all that auto generated stuff at the end.

Comment: `kubectl delete pod <pod>` as of today.

Answer (score 3):

Pods are ephemeral resources in Kubernetes and cannot be restarted.

If you delete a pods from a deployment Kubernetes will try to reconcile the state of the deployment by starting another pod effectively restarting your pod.